# Basic Pokedex in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, pokemon

I recently started learning C++ about a week ago, and I made a bit of progress. In honor of *Pokemon Go* releasing, I decided to make a Pokedex with the original 151 Pokemon. So far I have 120 or so of them in there and it works PERFECTLY! (Thank goodness). I believe my code could be much more efficient and work better. I probably am using bad practices too. If I am, please feel free to tell me and if you find a problem, tell me!

**Pokemon.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>


class Pokemon {
public:
    std::string type;
    double weight, height;
    std::string Gender;
    int evoLevel;
    bool finalEvo;
    int dexNum;
    std::string name;

    Pokemon(std::string name2, std::string type2, double weight2, double height2, std::string Gender2, int evoLevel2, bool finalEvo2, int dexNum2);
    Pokemon();
};
```

**Pokemon.cpp:**

```
#include "Pokemon.h"

Pokemon::Pokemon(std::string name2, std::string type2, double weight2,  double height2, std::string Gender2, int evoLevel2, bool finalEvo2, int dexNum2) {
    name = name2;
    type = type2;
    weight = weight2;
    height = height2;
    Gender = Gender2;
    evoLevel = evoLevel2;
    finalEvo = finalEvo2;
    dexNum = dexNum2;
}

//Default constructer
Pokemon::Pokemon() {
    name = "Pichario";
    type = "Death";
    weight = 10;
    height = 12;
    Gender = "Male and Female";
    evoLevel = 1;
    finalEvo = true;
    dexNum = 999;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Pokemon.h"


int main() {
    //Create Pokemon objects
    Pokemon bulbasaur("Bulbasaur", "Grass and Poison", 15.2, 28, "Male and Female", 1, false, 1);
    Pokemon ivysaur("Ivysaur", "Grass and Poison", 28.7, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 2);
    Pokemon venusaur("Venusaur", "Grass and Poison", 220.5, 79, "Male and Female", 3, true, 3);

    Pokemon charmander("Charmander", "Fire", 18.7, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 4);
    Pokemon charmeleon("Charmeleon", "Fire", 41.9, 44, "Male and Female", 2, false, 5);
    Pokemon charizard("Charizard", "Fire and Flying", 199.5, 67, "Male and Female", 3, true, 6);

    Pokemon squirtle("Squirtle", "Water", 19.8, 20, "Male and Female", 1, false, 7);
    Pokemon wartortle("Wartortle", "Water", 49.6, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 8);
    Pokemon blastoise("Blastoise", "Water", 188.5, 63, "Male and Female", 3, true, 9);

    Pokemon caterpie("Caterpie", "Bug", 6.4, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 10);
    Pokemon metapod("Metapod", "Bug", 21.8, 28, "Male and Female", 2, false, 11);
    Pokemon butterfree("Butterfree", "Bug and Flying", 70.5, 43, "Male and Female", 3, true, 12);

    Pokemon weedle("Weedle", "Bug and Poison", 7.1, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 13);
    Pokemon kakuna("Kakuna", "Bug and Poison", 22, 24, "Male and Female", 2, false, 14);
    Pokemon beedrill("Beedrill", "Bug and Poison", 65, 39, "Male and Female", 3, true, 15);

    Pokemon pidgey("Pidgey", "Normal and Flying", 4, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 16);
    Pokemon pidgeotto("Pidgeotto", "Normal and Flying", 66.1, 43, "Male and Female", 2, false, 17);
    Pokemon pidgeot("Pidgeot", "Normal and Flying", 87.1, 59, "Male and Female", 3, true, 18);

    Pokemon rattata("Rattata", "Normal", 7.7, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 19);
    Pokemon raticate("Raticate", "Normal", 40.8, 28, "Male and Female", 2, true, 20);

    Pokemon spearow("Spearow", "Normal and Flying", 4.4, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 21);
    Pokemon fearow("Fearow", "Normal and Flying", 83.8, 47, "Male and Female", 2, true, 22);

    Pokemon ekans("Ekans", "Poison", 15.2, 79, "Male and Female", 1, false, 23);
    Pokemon arbok("Arbok", "Poison", 143.3, 138, "Male and Female", 2, true, 24);

    Pokemon pikachu("Pikachu", "Electric", 13.2, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 25);
    Pokemon raichu("Raichu", "Electric", 66.1, 31, "Male and Female", 2, true, 26);

    Pokemon sandshrew("Sandshrew", "Ground", 26.5, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 27);
    Pokemon sandslash("Sandslash", "Ground", 65, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 28);

    Pokemon nidoranf("Nidoran female", "Poison", 15.4, 16, "Female", 1, false, 29);
    Pokemon nidorina("Nidorina", "Poison", 44.1, 31, "Female", 2, false, 30);
    Pokemon nidoqueen("Nidoqueen", "Poison and Ground", 132.3, 51, "Female", 3, true, 31);

    Pokemon nidoranm("Nidoran Male", "Poison", 19.8, 20, "Male", 1, false, 32);
    Pokemon nidorino("Nidorino", "Poison", 43, 35, "Male", 2, false, 33);
    Pokemon nidoking("Nidoking", "Poison and Ground", 136.7, 55, "Male", 3, true, 34);

    Pokemon clefairy("Clefairy", "Fairy", 16.5, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 35);
    Pokemon clefable("Clefable", "Fairy", 88.2, 51, "Male and Female", 2, true, 36);

    Pokemon vulpix("Vulpix", "Fire", 21.8, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 37);
    Pokemon ninetales("Ninetales", "Fire", 43.9, 43, "Male and Female", 2, true, 38);

    Pokemon jigglypuff("Jigglypuff", "Normal and Fairy", 12.1, 20, "Male and Female", 1, false, 39);
    Pokemon wigglytuff("Wigglytuff", "Normal and Fairy", 26.5, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 40);

    Pokemon zubat("Zubat", "Poison and Flying", 16.5, 31, "Male and Female", 1, false, 41);
    Pokemon golbat("Golbat", "Poison and Flying", 121.3, 63, "Male and Female", 2, true, 42);

    Pokemon oddish("Oddish", "Grass and Poison", 11.9, 20, "Male and Female", 1, false, 43);
    Pokemon gloom("Gloom", "Grass and Poison", 19, 31, "Male and Female", 2, false, 44);
    Pokemon vileplume("Vileplume", "Grass and Poison", 41, 47, "Male and Female", 3, true, 45);

    Pokemon paras("Paras", "Bug and Grass", 11.9, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 46);
    Pokemon parasect("Parasect", "Bug and Grass", 65, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 47);

    Pokemon venonat("Venonat", "Bug and Poison", 66.1, 39, "Male and Female", 1, false, 48);
    Pokemon venomoth("Venomoth", "Bug and Poison", 27.6, 59, "Male and Female", 2, true, 49);

    Pokemon diglett("Diglett", "Ground", 1.8, 8, "Male and Female", 1, false, 50);
    Pokemon dugtrio("Dugtrio", "Ground", 73.4, 28, "Male and Female", 2, true, 51);

    Pokemon meowth("Meowth", "Normal", 9.3, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 52);
    Pokemon persian("Persian", "Normal", 70.5, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 53);

    Pokemon psyduck("Psyduck", "Water", 43.2, 31, "Male and Female", 1, false, 54);
    Pokemon golduck("Golduck", "Water", 168.9, 67, "Male and Female", 2, true, 55);

    Pokemon mankey("Mankey", "Fighting", 61.7, 20, "Male and Female", 1, false, 56);
    Pokemon primeape("Primeape", "Fighting", 70.5, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 57);

    Pokemon growlithe("Growlithe", "Fire", 41.9, 28, "Male and Female", 1, false, 58);
    Pokemon arcanine("Arcanine", "Fire", 341.7, 63, "Male and Female", 2, true, 59);

    Pokemon poliwag("Poliwag", "Water", 27.3, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 60);
    Pokemon poliwhirl("Poliwhirl", "Water", 44.1, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 61);
    Pokemon poliwrath("Poliwrath", "Water and Fighting", 119, 51, "Male and Female", 3, true, 62);

    Pokemon abra("Abra", "Psychic", 43, 35, "Male and Female", 1, false, 63);
    Pokemon kadabra("Kadabra", "Psychic", 124.6, 51, "Male and Female", 2, false, 64);
    Pokemon alakazam("Alakazam", "Psychic", 105.8, 59, "Male and Female", 3, true, 65);

    Pokemon machop("Machop", "Fighting", 43, 31, "Male and Female", 1, false, 66);
    Pokemon machoke("Machoke", "Fighting", 155.4, 59, "Male and Female", 2, false, 67);
    Pokemon machamp("Machamp", "Fighting", 286.6, 63, "Male and Female", 3, true, 68);

    Pokemon bellsprout("Bellsprout", "Grass and Poison", 8.8, 28, "Male and Female", 1, false, 69);
    Pokemon weepinbell("Weepinbell", "Grass and Poison", 14.1, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 70);
    Pokemon victreebel("Victreebel", "Grass and Poison", 34.2, 67, "Male and Female", 3, true, 71);

    Pokemon tentacool("Tentacool", "Water and Poison", 100.3, 35, "Male and Female", 1, false, 72);
    Pokemon tentacruel("Tentacruel", "Water and Poison", 121.3, 63, "Male and Female", 2, true, 73);

    Pokemon geodude("Geodude", "Rock and Ground", 44.1, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 74);
    Pokemon graveler("Graveler", "Rock and Ground", 231.5, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 75);
    Pokemon golem("Golem", "Rock and Ground", 661.4, 31, "Male and Female", 3, true, 76);

    Pokemon ponyta("Ponyta", "Fire", 66.1, 39, "Male and Female", 1, false, 77);
    Pokemon rapidash("Rapidash", "Fire", 209.4, 67, "Male and Female", 2, true, 78);

    Pokemon slowpoke("Slowpoke", "Water and Psychic", 79.4, 47, "Male and Female", 1, false, 79);
    Pokemon slowbro("Slowbro", "Water and Psychic", 173.1, 63, "Male and Female", 2, true, 80);

    Pokemon magnemite("Magnemite", "Electric and Steel", 13.2, 12, "Unknown", 1, false, 81);
    Pokemon magneton("Magneton", "Electric and Steel", 132.3, 39, "Unknown", 2, true, 82);

    Pokemon farfetchd("Farfetch'd", "Normal and Flying", 33.1, 31, "Male and Female", 1, true, 83);

    Pokemon doduo("Doduo", "Normal and Flying", 86.4, 45, "Male and Female", 1, false, 84);
    Pokemon dodrio("Dodrio", "Normal and Flying", 187.8, 71, "Male and Female", 2, true, 85);

    Pokemon seel("Seel", "Water", 198.4, 43, "Male and Female", 1, false, 86);
    Pokemon dewgong("Dewgong", "Water and Ice", 264.6, 67, "Male and Female", 2, true, 87);

    Pokemon grimer("Grimer", "Poison", 66.1, 35, "Male and Female", 1, false, 88);
    Pokemon muk("Muk", "Poison", 66.1, 47, "Male and Female", 2, true, 89);

    Pokemon shellder("Shellder", "Water", 8.8, 12, "Male and Female", 1, false, 90);
    Pokemon cloyster("Cloyster", "Water and Ice", 292.1, 59, "Male and Female", 2, true, 91);

    Pokemon gastly("Gastly", "Ghost and Poison", 0.2, 51, "Male and Female", 1, false, 92);
    Pokemon haunter("Haunter", "Ghost and Poison", 0.2, 63, "Male and Female", 2, false, 93);
    Pokemon gangar("Gengar", "Ghost and Poison", 89.3, 59, "Male and Female", 3, true, 94);

    Pokemon onix("Onix", "Rock and Ground", 463, 346, "Male and Female", 1, true, 95);

    Pokemon drowzee("Drowzee", "Psychic", 71.4, 39, "Male and Female", 1, false, 96);
    Pokemon hypno("Hypno", "Psychic", 166.7, 63, "Male and Female", 2, true, 97);

    Pokemon krabby("Krabby", "Water", 14.3, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 98);
    Pokemon kingler("Kingler", "Water", 132.3, 51, "Male and Female", 2, true, 99);

    Pokemon voltorb("Voltorb", "Electric", 22.9, 20, "Unknown", 1, false, 100);
    Pokemon electrode("Electrode", "Electric", 146.8, 47, "Male and Female", 2, true, 101);

    Pokemon exeggcute("Exeggcute", "Grass and Psychic", 5.5, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 102);
    Pokemon exeggutor("Exeggutor", "Grass and Psychic", 264.6, 79, "Male and Female", 2, true, 103);

    Pokemon cubone("Cubone", "Ground", 14.3, 16, "Male and Female", 1, false, 104);
    Pokemon marowak("Marowak", "Ground", 99.2, 39, "Male and Female", 2, true, 105);

    Pokemon hitmonlee("Hitmonlee", "Fighting", 109.8, 59, "Male", 1, true, 106);
    Pokemon hitmonchan("Hitmonchan", "Fighting", 110.7, 55, "Male", 1, true, 107);

    Pokemon lickitung("Lickitung", "Normal", 144.4, 47, "Male and Female", 1, true, 108);

    Pokemon koffing("Koffing", "Poison", 2.2, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 109);
    Pokemon weezing("Weezing", "Poison", 20.9, 47, "Male and Female", 2, true, 110);

    Pokemon rhyhorn("Rhyhorn", "Ground and Rock", 253.5, 39, "Male and Female", 1, false, 111);
    Pokemon rhydon("Rhydon", "Ground and Rock", 264.6, 75, "Male and Female", 2, true, 112);

    Pokemon chansey("Chansey", "Normal", 76.3, 43, "Female", 1, true, 113);

    Pokemon tangela("Tangela", "Grass", 77.2, 39, "Male and Female", 1, true, 114);

    Pokemon kangaskhan("Kangaskhan", "Normal", 176.4, 87, "Female", 1, true, 115);

    Pokemon horsea("Horsea", "Water", 17.6, 16, "Male and Gender", 1, false, 116);
    Pokemon seadra("Seadra", "Water", 55.1, 47, "Male and Female", 2, true, 117);

    Pokemon goldeen("Goldeen", "Water", 33.1, 24, "Male and Female", 1, false, 118);
    Pokemon seaking("Seaking", "Water", 86, 51, "Male and Female", 2, true, 119);

    Pokemon staryu("Staryu", "Water", 76.1, 31, "Unknown", 1, false, 120);
    Pokemon starmie("Starmie", "Water and Psychic", 176.4, 43, "Unknown", 2, true, 121);

    Pokemon mrmime("Mr. Mime", "Fairy and Psychic", 120, 51, "Male and Female", 1, true, 122);

    Pokemon scyther("Scyther", "Bug and Flying", 123.5, 59, "Male and Female", 1, true, 123);
    //Create a vector with all of the pokemon
    std::vector<Pokemon> pokemon = { bulbasaur, ivysaur, venusaur,
        charmander, charmeleon, charizard,
        squirtle, wartortle, blastoise,
        caterpie, metapod, butterfree,
        weedle, kakuna, beedrill,
        pidgey, pidgeotto, pidgeot,
        rattata, raticate,
        spearow, fearow,
        ekans, arbok,
        pikachu, raichu,
        sandshrew, sandslash,
        nidoranf, nidorina, nidoqueen,
        nidoranm, nidorino, nidoking,
        clefairy, clefable,
        vulpix, ninetales,
        jigglypuff, wigglytuff,
        zubat, golbat,
        oddish, gloom, vileplume,
        paras, parasect,
        meowth, persian,
        psyduck, golduck,
        mankey, primeape,
        growlithe, arcanine,
        poliwag, poliwhirl, poliwrath,
        abra, kadabra, alakazam,
        machop, machoke, machamp,
        bellsprout, weepinbell, victreebel,
        tentacool, tentacruel,
        geodude, graveler, golem,
        ponyta, rapidash,
        slowpoke, slowbro,
        magnemite, magneton,
        farfetchd,
        doduo, dodrio,
        seel, dewgong,
        grimer, muk,
        shellder, cloyster,
        gastly, haunter, gangar,
        onix,
        drowzee, hypno,
        krabby, kingler,
        voltorb, electrode,
        exeggcute, exeggutor,
        cubone, marowak,
        hitmonlee, hitmonchan,
        lickitung,
        koffing, weezing,
        rhyhorn, rhydon,
        chansey,
        tangela,
        kangaskhan,
        horsea, seadra,
        goldeen, seaking,
        staryu, starmie,
        mrmime,
        scyther };

    //Ask the user which way they would like to search
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Pokedex! We have the first " << pokemon.size() + 4 << " pokemon indexed!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Would you like to search by name, number, or type?" << std::endl;
    std::string input = "";
    std::cin >> input;
    //make input uppercase
    for (int p = 0; p < input.size(); p++) {
        input[p] = toupper(input[p]);
    }
    //check for input
    if (input == "NAME") {
        //Ask for name
        std::cout << "Enter the name of the pokemon" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        bool found = false;
        //make name lowercase
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
            input[j] = tolower(input[j]);
        }
        //make first letter uppercase
        input[0] = toupper(input[0]);

        //loop through vector
        for (int i = 0; i < pokemon.size(); i++) {
            //check if input is the same as a pokemon name
            if (input == pokemon.at(i).name) {
                std::cout << "The pokemon " << pokemon.at(i).name << " has been found!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is a " << pokemon.at(i).type << " type." << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << "'s weight and height are: " << pokemon.at(i).weight << " lbs and " << pokemon.at(i).height << " inches." << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << "'s gender is " << pokemon.at(i).Gender << std::endl;

                if (pokemon.at(i).finalEvo) {
                    std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is the final evolution in its line." << std::endl;

                    if (pokemon.at(i).evoLevel > 1) {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is what " << pokemon.at(i - 1).name << " evolves into." << std::endl;
                    } 
                    else {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is the only pokemon in its evolution line" << std::endl;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " evolves into " << pokemon.at(i + 1).name << std::endl;
                    if (pokemon.at(i).evoLevel > 1) {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is what " << pokemon.at(i - 1).name << " evolves into." << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //what to do if invalid pokemon is entered
        if (found == false) {
            std::cerr << "Pokemon not found!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (input == "TYPE") {
        //get input
        std::string input = "";
        std::cout << "Enter the type you would like!" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
        //make input lowercase
        for (int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
            input[k] = tolower(input[k]);
        }
        //make first letter uppercase
        input[0] = toupper(input[0]);

        //loop through vector
        for (int i = 0; i < pokemon.size(); i++) {
            //see if pokemon type contains the input
            if (pokemon.at(i).type.find(input) != std::string::npos) {
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is a " << pokemon.at(i).type << " type!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Enter the number of the pokemon" << std::endl;
        int input = 1;
        std::cin >> input;
        bool found = false;

        std::cout << input << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < pokemon.size(); i++) {
            //see if pokemon has same num as input
            if (input == pokemon.at(i).dexNum) {
                std::cout << "The pokemon " << pokemon.at(i).name << " has been found!" << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is a " << pokemon.at(i).type << " type." << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << "'s weight and height are: " << pokemon.at(i).weight << " lbs and " << pokemon.at(i).height << " inches." << std::endl;
                std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << "'s gender is " << pokemon.at(i).Gender << std::endl;

                if (pokemon.at(i).finalEvo) {
                    std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is the final evolution in its line." << std::endl;
                    if (pokemon.at(i).evoLevel > 1) {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is what " << pokemon.at(i - 1).name << " evolves into." << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is the only pokemon in its evolution line" << std::endl;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " evolves into " << pokemon.at(i + 1).name << std::endl;
                    if (pokemon.at(i).evoLevel > 1) {
                        std::cout << pokemon.at(i).name << " is what " << pokemon.at(i - 1).name << " evolves into." << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //Say pokemon wasnt 
        if (found == false) {
            std::cerr << "Pokemon not found!" << std::endl;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Pichario" isn't a real Pokemon. I would lose the default ctor.

Comment: Your `finalEvo` and `evoLevel` logic doesn't jive well with the Eeveelutions. Jolteon (#135) does not evolve into Flareon (#136), and Eevee (#133) is not restricted to evolving into Vaporeon (#134).

Comment: Am I the only one who sees questions like this and thinks that people should really be designing schemas in some database instead of classes in some OO language? If I were you, I'd be storing all this information in a database, and then I'd use some C++ SQL client to do stuff with that data. I realize that you're just learning C++, but this is why I think people should really learn SQL first.

Comment: Make sure you don't do *any* buffer checks; there are 106 extra Pokémon that you probably don't know about.

Comment: rather than typing in an entire pokédex by hand, perhaps look for something that's already done the work for you  :)  https://github.com/veekun/pokedex/

Comment: @michaelsnowden +1, though as a learning project and as it's essentially one big table he could do with a text file and read from it.

Comment: @michaelsnowden I disagree, in part because if you can only use SQL but not anything else you'll have a hard time using it for any real application (also wheres the love for NoSQL), but mostly because you shouldn't necessarily default to a database for data storage and retrieval; text files, some source code, a web api, or a database may all make sense as a data source depending on your application. What you should really be doing is that making sure your abstraction makes it easy to ignore where the data comes from, and swap where it comes from.

Comment: You do know @Eevee does evolve: baby -> kid -> teen -> adult etc.

Comment: `pokedex.size() + 4` What's that magic number `4` doing there?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

## Your Pokemon class (declaration)

```
class Pokemon {
public:
    std::string type;
    double weight, height;
    std::string Gender;
    int evoLevel;
    bool finalEvo;
    int dexNum;
    std::string name;

    Pokemon(std::string name2, std::string type2, double weight2, double height2, std::string Gender2, int evoLevel2, bool finalEvo2, int dexNum2);
    Pokemon();
};
```

Here are several things that spring to eye. First of all, all your fields are public. This indicates that you want a `struct`, not a `class`. In C++, they only differ by the default visibility. `class` is `private` by default, `struct` is `public` by default. So let's change that:

```
struct Pokemon {
```

Next, we should disable `Pokemon()`. That way, one cannot create a pokemon by accident:

```
    Pokemon() = delete;
```

Note that this isn't necessary, since any constructor will prevent the compiler from providing a default one.

### Better types

In your other constructor, we change the name of the arguments and their types slightly:

```
    Pokemon(Name name, Type type, Weight weight, Height height, Gender gender, 
            EvoLevel level, bool finalEvolution, PokedexID pid);
```

Wait. What the hell are all those types? First of all, ***they are an overkill***. Second of all, they [follow the C++ core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-typed). You don't want to use a Pokemon's name for its gender by accident, do you?

### Handling the Pokemon's type

Which brings us to enumerations. `Type` and `Gender` are perfect candidates for those:

```
enum class BasicType {
   Fire,
   Grass,
   Water,
   Electro,
   Poison,
   ...
};
```

Since Pokemon can have several types, we use another type `Type` to combine them:

```
class Type{ 
    Type(BasicType main);
    Type(BasicType main, BasicType sub);

    void addSubType(BasicType);
    bool hasType(BasicType) const;
};
```

I'm not sure whether Pokemon will ever have more than two types, but as @Eeevee noticed, they are ordered.

If you want, you can define syntactic sugar upon this with by overloading `operator|`:

```
Type operator|(BasicType main, BasicType sub) { return Type(main, sub); }
Type operator|(Type a,         BasicType sub) { return a.addSubtype(sub); }
```

The operator [enables us to use `Type::Fire | Type::Poison`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1448396/1139697). Note that this is probably again an overkill. However, it will prevent you from using

```
Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "Gras and Poison", ...);
```

Instead, if you use

```
Pokemon("Bulbasaur", Type::Gras | Type::Poison, ...);
```

you end up with a compiler error, instead of a frustrated user not able to find "Bulbasaur" by type "Grass". For testing, an `operator&` might come in handy:

```
Type operator&(Type      a, BasicType b) { return a.hasType(b); }
Type operator&(BasicType a, Type      b) { return b.hasType(a); }
```

That's very basic, but it gets its job done. How you actually store the types is left as an exercise, but not too hard. Note that you can add arbitrary methods to `Type` or functions that take `Type` as an argument, so there is enough space for additional <del>mad science experiments</del> features.

### A gender study

We can do the same for gender, although it's slightly easier here, since there are only some and therefore we don't need the `operator|` trick or `addSubType`:

```
enum class Gender {
   Male,
   Female,
   Both,
   Unknown
};
```

Again, this prevents you from writing

```
Pokemon("Bulbasaur", Type::Grass | Type::Poison, 15.2, 28, "Apache helicopter", ...);
```

### Putting it all together

For the other types, for the sake of simplicity, we say

```
typedef std::string Name;
typedef double Weight;
typedef double Height;
typedef unsigned int EvoLevel;
typedef unsigned int PokedexID;
```

Therefore, we end up with the following struct:

```
struct Pokemon {
    Pokemon() = delete;
    Pokemon(Name name, Type type, Weight weight, Height height, Gender gender, 
            EvoLevel level, bool isFinalEvolution, PokedexID pid);

  Name name;
    Type type;
    Weight weight;
    Height height;
    Gender gender;
    EvoLevel evolutionLevel;
    bool isFinalEvolution;
    PokedexID pid;
};
```

Note that contrary to your code, all variables here **strictly** follow camelCase, whereas your code contained `Gender`. Also notice that in `class` objects the members are usually prefixed with `m_`, suffixed with `_` or follow another naming convention. Since you want to use it without encapsulation and all public (e.g. `pokemon.type`) prefixes or suffixes would make your code harder to read here.

*"But wait,"*, I here you say. *"Now the arguments have the same name as my members!"*. And that's good. If someone uses `Pokemon::Pokemon(...)` in their program, they want their IDE to show the argument names in a nice way, *without* the 2 as suffix.

Which brings us to your constructor's implementation:

```
// your code
#include "Pokemon.h"

Pokemon::Pokemon(std::string name2, std::string type2, double weight2,  double height2, std::string Gender2, int evoLevel2, bool finalEvo2, int dexNum2) {
    name = name2;
    type = type2;
    weight = weight2;
    height = height2;
    Gender = Gender2;
    evoLevel = evoLevel2;
    finalEvo = finalEvo2;
    dexNum = dexNum2;
}
```

Aha. First of all, if you have an argument that has the same name as a member, you can use `this->[membername]` to distinguish, e.g.

```
this->name = name2;
```

However, we're in a constructor. Therefore, we can [*initialize* our values](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Note that [this isn't necessary with a POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list), but some of your members are classes, for example `Name` (it's a `std::string`). This saves a copy. We end up with:

```
Pokemon(Name name, Type type, Weight weight, Height height, Gender gender, 
        EvoLevel level, bool isFinalEvolution, PokedexID pid) 
 : name(std::move(name)), type(type), weight(weight), height(height), gender(gender),
   evolutionLevel(evolutionLevel), isFinalEvolution(isFinalEvolution), pid(pid) {
}
```

Note that this indicates that we didn't really *need* have defined a constructor, we could just have used our usual [`struct` initialisation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516657/c-structure-initialization)

```
Pokemon bulbasaur = { "Bulbasaur", ... };
```

But depending on your types, that's slightly more error prone.

## Output and DRY

You don't follow the Don't-Repeat-Yourself principle. Your code contains the facilities to print a Pokemon *twice*. This is bad, since changes on one part should probably also be done on the other, but get lost. Instead, provide a operator, if you want to use `std::cout`:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Pokemon & pokemon) {
    out << pokemon.name << " is a " << pokemon.type << " type.\n"
        << pokemon.name << "'s weight and height are: " 
        << pokemon.weight << " lbs and " << pokemon.height << " inches.\n";
        << pokemon.name << "'s gender is " << pokemon.gender << "\n";

    if (pokemon.isFinalEvolution) {
        out << pokemon.name << " is the final evolution in its line.\n";
    }
    ...
    return out;
}
```

Note that this also needs `operator<<` on all types used in `Pokemon`, e.g. `Gender` and `Type`.

## The database

So here's my greatest pet peeve with your code. Your `main`:

```
Pokemon bulbasaur("Bulbasaur", "Grass and Poison", 15.2, 28, "Male and Female", 1, false, 1);
Pokemon ivysaur("Ivysaur", "Grass and Poison", 28.7, 39, "Male and Female", 2, false, 2);
Pokemon venusaur("Venusaur", "Grass and Poison", 220.5, 79, "Male and Female", 3, true, 3);
...
```

There are two things I'm not fond of here. First of all, you only use the names "bulbasaur" or "ivysaur" once later, in `std::vector<Pokemon> pokemon`, so you're polluting the local namespace. Instead, fill your vector directly:

```
std::vector<Pokemon> pokedex = { 
    Pokemon("Bulbasaur", Type::Grass | Type::Poison, 15.2, 28, Gender::Both, 1, false, 1),
    Pokemon("Ivysaur", Type::Grass | Type::Poison, 28.7, 39, Gender::Both, 2, false, 2),
    ...
};
```

***But that's not how you should do it.***

> So far I have 120 or so of them in there and it works PERFECTLY!

You're entering all of them by hand. That's insane. Let's say you've messed the lbs up of Pikachu, or you want to add more Pokemon later. You will always have to edit your program and compile it. That's bad. It's error prone. And the errors are hard (compiling) to fix.

Instead, have all your Pokemon in an external file. You can then read from that file into your vector easily (if you write the streaming operator):

```
while(pokeFile >> pokemon){
    pokedex.push_back(pokemon);
}
```

That's all that's necessary, apart from getting the Pokemon data into the external file and writing `istream& operator>>(istream&, Pokemon&)`. Instead of a `main` that gets larger with every other Pokemon generation, you only have to change your `Pokemon.txt` file. You can even translate it to other languages (e.g. "Bisasam", "Bisaknosp", "Bisaflor",...), but that's a little bit far at this point.

## Other stuff

If you don't need the index, use a range-based `for` loop instead of `operator[]`. Also, you've shadowed the variable `input` several times. Don't. Furthermore strive for smaller functions, your `main` was too large.

If you're using C++11, use the range-based `for` loop more often.

Also if you don't want to modify a variable, use `const`. Your `std::vector<Pokemon>` is a perfect candidate for this, since you don't want to change it afterwards.

Concerning `ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Pokemon&)`, we've lost the ability to print the previous/next evolution, but that's by design, since you need access on the whole Pokedex for that (and there are possibly several evoltions for a single Pokemon, looking at you, Eevee). That's something you should probably think about a little bit more. You could store the ID of the previous Pokemon instead, or use an invalid ID if it does not exist. But that's left as an exercise.

Last but not least, if you were to write a productive Pokedex, use libraries that enable you to use database(-like) functions, for example SQLite, and/or abstract the queries behind a class, like

```
class Pokedex {
public:
    template<class F>
    Result find_one(F && f){
        return from_it(std::find(internal_list.begin(), internal_list.end(), f));
    }
    ResultList find_all(F && f){
        ResultList results;
        std::copy_if(internal_list.begin(), internal_list.end(), ...);
        return results;
    }
};
```

depending how complex your queries should be.

## Your "new" main

So, following the remarks above, I've somewhat rewritten your `main`. The Pokemon are gone from the cage of your code, instead they roam in some other <del>Pokeball</del> file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Pokemon.h"

typedef std::vector<Pokemon> Pokedex;

std::string to_pokecase(const std::string & str){
    // excercise, should make "Bulbasaur" from "buLbaSAUR".
}

bool print_pokemon_by_name(const Pokedex & pokedex){
    //Ask for name
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the pokemon" << std::endl;
    Name input_name;
    std::cin >> input_name;

    input_name = to_pokecase(input_name);

    for (auto & thePokemon : pokedex) {
        if (input_name == thePokemon.name) {
            std::cout << "The pokemon " << thePokemon.name << " has been found!\n" 
                      << thePokemon<< std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

    std::cerr << "Pokemon not found!" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

bool print_pokemons_by_type(const Pokedex & pokedex){
    // exercise
}

bool print_pokemon_by_number(const Pokedex & pokedex){
    // exercise
}

std::vector<Pokemon> read_pokemons_from_file(const std::string & fileName){
    // exercise
}

int main() {
    const auto pokedex = read_pokemons_from_file("Pokemon.txt");

    //Ask the user which way they would like to search
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Pokedex! We have the first " << pokedex.size() + 4 << " pokemon indexed!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Would you like to search by name, number, or type?" << std::endl;
    std::string input = "";
    std::cin >> input;

    //make input uppercase
    for (auto & p : input) {
        p = toupper(p);
    }

    if (input == "NAME") {
        print_pokemon_by_name(pokedex);
    }
    else if (input == "TYPE") {
        print_pokemons_by_type(pokedex);
    }
    else if (input == "NUMBER") {
        print_pokemon_by_number(pokedex);    
    } else {
        // handle invalid input
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the new `main` is much smaller. It can be read on a screen without scrolling at all. All functionalities that differ have been extracted into other functions, which themselves are rather small again.

There are several things that can be further refactored and rewritten, but that's left as an exercise.

## Addendum: The specification

Thanks to all comments on this review and all the Pokemon specification I've missed in several revisions of this review, I guess this is a good place to add two things.

First of all, before you implement your class, ask yourself more questions: Can you easily test for (pokemon) types? Do you often test for them? Should that be in its own function? Do you test for names? Do you need to normalize names? More than once? Do the Pokemon's types need to be ordered?

Secondly, reflect the answers to those questions in your code, or, if the answer was negative, in your comments/documentation. Also, try to use higher-level code. The main above is already pretty high-level, with the effect that I can change `Pokedex` and `Pokemon` completely and never need to touch `main` at all.

Either way, good luck catching 'em all! May your Pokedex be complete.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42818/discussion-on-answer-by-zeta-basic-pokedex-in-c).

Comment: ´Pokemon() = delete;´ is not needed at all. Generally functions with more then 2 parameters are frowned upon. I would remove all constructors.

Comment: a set is not an appropriate data type for a pokémon's type — the types are ordered.  the order doesn't affect game mechanics, but it's always preserved in all official sources and has some flavor/lore impact.

Comment: @Eevee: Added. It's funny how that post got so much larger than originally intended. Anything else I missed? Except for (possible different) Pokemon descriptions? I really need to pick up a game.

Comment: Remove `Pokemon(Name name, Type type, Weight weight, Height height, Gender gender, 
        EvoLevel level, bool isFinalEvolution, PokedexID pid) ` ctor and use `{}`.  (Try it before you bash it)

Comment: A [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d6164609f93f63) with some typos fixed.

Comment: Great post, but I disagree with "Don't use std::vector<T>::at(i)". There's about a billion exploits and hard to find bugs in C++ code due to no bounds checking with `[]`. Yes there's some marginal overhead that can be elided most of the time by the compiler, but this won't matter at all here.

Comment: Why go through all the hassle of defining a separate class to store ordered `Type`s, when `std::vector<Type>` is standard, would preserve the insertion order, and could be constructed in a syntactically efficient way from an `std::initializer_list`? Also @Will `type` is not a keyword if that's what you mean, and otherwise, by trying to puristically keep the word _type_ for the language only, that means we'd have to use some other inaccurate term for the game universe... so there's no real way to win. ...Well, actually, qualifying with _C++type_ and _Pokemon type_ seems to work just fine.

Comment: *"In a production project, those questions would have to be answered by a software requirement specification, the software design or other documents"* - everywhere I worked there were no upfront specifications; the developers were responsible for refining the requirements on a daily basis.

Comment: @Voo `vector::at()` is great if the program is at risk of invalid indexes from user input, but that's about it. For situations where indexes _must_ be OK past the initial debug phase, the overhead of `at()` is totally unnecessary: (A) `assert` can suffice in simple cases, & (B) for more elaborate situations, common compilers provide debug versions of the STL that perform bounds-checking in `operator[]` - & thus meaning we don't have to find-and-replace all `at()`s for an optimised release build. Either way, I can't see how this "can be elided most of the time by the compiler"; can you explain?

Comment: @underscore If you're not shipping the debug code of your application, neither of those two things will help you. A great many people thought they could do the bounds checks explicitly when they thought they needed them and that has resulted in millions of exploits in basically every nontrivial C or C++ application out there. Yes there is a performance cost, but do you know how large it actually is? Even on a smartphone the cost is below 1ns. That won't matter here or in 99.99% of all code at all.

Comment: cont. And what I mean with "can be elided" is simple: In most cases the compiler has the knowledge it needs to show that it doesn't actually has to do all the comparisons but can avoid most of them. A classical example is if you're sequentially iterating through an array: The compiler can easily check once if you're ever going to access an out of bounds array and if not jump to the optimized code that's identical what'd be generated with `[]`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/UpAjB3) for an example, the inner loop is at the start of `.L8` - no bounds check in sight.

Comment: @Voo In case it wasn't clear, I very much agree with you for programs subject to exploits, which seem to be your emphasis. I was talking about programs not subject to malicious users, clumsy programmers, etc. - i.e. where indices are generated internally & guaranteed not to fail - having been rigorously tested, asserted, UBsan'd, etc. At that point, to me it's time for `operator[]` everywhere, as I've no need to bounds-check. Call that premature optimisation if you want. Still, I'm not saying it's likely to slow most programs down noticeably, nor that folk can't do it all the time if they want

Comment: @Voo and nice example, though I think it's a little artificial or at least highly context-sensitive: I imagine it completely depends upon the loop having been unrolled to use literal indices, which the compiler then deduces pass bounds-checks statically, hence eliding them at runtime. With a larger loop, one might not be so lucky, surely?

Comment: @underscore The size of the loop body actually has no influence. The optimization is based on dataflow analysis, which basically means the compiler determines a set of possible values for every variable at different points in the program. In our case we know that i is in the range [0, vec.size()-1]. With that information it can then deduce that all bounds checks are always false. In other situations the compiler first has to do rearrange code (say you get the end value passed in as a parameter) first before it can do this, but e.g. Java compilers have gotten pretty good at this.

Comment: We certainly can write code that can't be analysed by this, but most often the accesses are then complicated enough that the programmer won't be able to reason about the correctness in all edge cases either. Personally I'm just of the opinion that not doing bounds checks is rather dangerous and offers only rarely any noticeable payoffs. I'm happy to see that last time I checked the latest GSL classes also do bounds checking by default.

Comment: @Voo I removed the `::at` remarks, since I originally wanted to draw the conclusion `at() -> operator[] -> don't need index? range-based for` if the index isn't used anyway (except for sequential access), but it seems I've messed that up during cross-editing and stopped midway. Sorry. Either way I would argue that your approach would be easier with a `safe_vector`, that has `safe_vector::unsafe_at` (which is `vector::operator[]`) and `safe_vector::operator[]` (which is `vector::at`). I think rust's `std::vec::Vec` follows this approach, as well as `vector` in Haskell. But that's another topic.

Comment: @Zeta It's only a minor point and I absolutely agree about your remarks about range based for loops and co - you really should need neither of the two options very often in modern C++. I've never heard of `safe_vector` before and can't find  references via google (I was always tempted to write a small wrapper around `vector` that did exactly what it seems it is doing! Very nice). Any link for me?

Comment: @Voo: Sorry, I don't know of any C++ `safe_vector`, it was just a small gedankenexperiment. Rust provides something that [comes close to one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees). Swapping `std::vector::operator[]` and `std::vector::at` (and rename the latter to `unsafeAt`) in C++ via wrapper would be the first thing that comes into my mind, too.

Comment: @Zeta Ah misunderstood you. Yes I've played around with Rust quite a bit in the last while and I'm rather sold on it - bit of a learning curve that might distract from its mainstream appeal, but it solves many, many problems of the current crop of languages while still being great for low-level code.

Comment: The typedef has eventually been 'coded away' as the posts have gone on but a small point, if I understand correctly: ```cpp
typedef std::vector<Pokemon> Pokedex;
``` Should now be ```cpp
using Pokedex = std::vector<Pokemon>;
```
[See this post for reasons why](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1193988140/how-cplusplus-using-or-aliasdeclaration-is-better-than-typedef) Final final point, 'using' statements generally shoundn't be in the global namespace, but this is a small project in it's current state, th

Comment: This answer has a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42818/discussion-on-answer-by-zeta-basic-pokedex-in-c). Everyone with 20 rep and over can further discuss it there. I can not move comments to chat a second time. All comments below this comment will be removed.

Answer (score 35):

Just a few things that seem like they might be open to improvement.

#### Evolution

Rather than having a Boolean to indicate whether a particular type is the final step in its evolution, I think I'd have an "evolvesTo" field to give the `dexNum` of the type to which this evolves, and (probably) use a special value such as `-1` to indicate that it doesn't evolve into anything else. I'd probably also add a similar field for "evolvesFrom". At least in my opinion, encoding the information directly is much cleaner than depending on the order of records.

#### Database

Rather than having all that raw data embedded into the program, I'd at least consider moving it into an external file, which you'd then read in when you start the program. Doesn't have to be anything complex or special--for example, I'd consider something like one Pokemon per line, with a tab between each field.

#### Constructor

It's generally preferable to initialize members with a member initializer list rather than assign to them in the body of a constructor. When you do this, the compiler can sort out which is the parameter and which is the member, so you don't need to add a `2` to each parameter name to keep them straight:

```
Pokemon::Pokemon(std::string name, std::string type, double weight,  double height, std::string Gender, int evoLevel, bool finalEvo, int dexNum) 
    : name(name),
      type(type),
      weight(weight),
      height(height),
      Gender(Gender),
      evoLevel(evoLevel),
      finalEvo(finalEvo),
      dexNum(dexNum),
{}
```

#### Searching

You have quite a few instances of searching through your database to find Pokemon based on various attributes. Nearly all these can be implemented with `std::find_if` to do the actual searching.

```
auto p = std::find_if(pokemon.begin(), pokemon.end(),
    [&](int dexNum) { return dexNum == input; });

if (p == pokemon.end())
    std::cout << "Sorry, I can't find that Pokemon.\n";
else {
    std::cout << "The Pokemon: " << p->name << " has been found.\n";
    std::cout << p->name << " is a " << p->type << " type Pokemon\n";
    // ...
}
```

If you were dealing with a lot more data (tens of thousands or tens of millions of items) there are more efficient ways of searching data, such as building an index for each field you want to search by. If you want to experiment with one implementation of this, the Boost [Multi Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library provides this type of functionality.

On the other hand, if you have to deal with that amount of data, you probably want to use some sort of database anyway (e.g., [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)).

Comment: +1 for the database suggestion. Also, table design: tables for the pokemon themselves, type, gender, and evolution path. More at <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model> <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram> <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design>

Comment: The evolution suggestion is good, but there are several possible evolutions. Take Eevee for example. It can evolve into Vaporeon, Jolteon, Flareon, Espeon, and several others, so `evolveTo` has to be a set or something similar. On the other hand `evolveFrom` would be either one or none.

Comment: Seems overkill to capture everything by reference in your lambda, when you only need to capture `input`.

Comment: @cloakedlearning: even with a default capture, a lambda still only captures what's used in the lambda.

Comment: @cloakedlearning: If you want the gory details, they're in [expr.prim.lambda]/12 of the standard/draft standard. Most of the relevant part is: "A lambda-expression with an associated capture-default [...] is said to implicitly capture the entity (i.e., this or a variable) if the compound-statement: odr-uses the entity, or names the entity in a potentially-evaluated expression [...]".

Answer (score 11):

The biggest problem I see with your code is Eevee.

Eevee has a branched evolution.

My fix is to have a vector with the dex number of the evolutions (And if you wanted to get fancy it would be a struct with the details of the evolution. (Type,Level and dex number )

Comment: And additional tools needed for the evolution, e.g. water stone.

Comment: This also becomes important if OP intends to go beyond the original 151, since Gen 2 and onward started introducing out-of-order evolutionary lines.

Comment: I did think about Eeveelutions until I made this question... lol :P. Right now, I have it hard coded into the code. It is saying that if it's Jolteon, Vaporeon, etc. It says [pokemon] is what Eevee evolves into. Very inefficient and messy but it works :P.

Comment: Eevee is not the only branched evolution. As far back as generation II, pokemon such as Gloom, Polywhirl and Slowpoke were granted branched evolutions.

Comment: Better solution would be an `int evolvesFrom` field guaranteeing one to many relationship. It would make searching for final forms a bit more complex, but that can be done once per program run and the index is just a simple integer so it's just a blink of an eye.

Comment: What does _Type_ mean here? If it's the type that the Pokemon will evolve to, that's redundant as the linked 'Dex record will provide that info. Or do you mean the mode of evolution, i.e. level/Stone/something else? In which case, that _Level_ won't always be applicable either. Nice idea, but it wouldn't suffice as it is.

Answer (score 8):

So you wanna be a master of Pokemon? Do you have the skills to make a Pokedex?

The Pokedex is a piece of complicated machinery. As a result, this code review will be more focused on the conceptual approach; how your data relates to other data and the best ways to represent that data. It will not cover implementation details, such as whether the actual data is derived from text files, databases, is hardcoded, etc. Nor will it cover how best to organize the code in different files. So... here we go...

There are quite a lot of things to think about when creating a Pokedex, even one as simple as what you've got going on. So first we'll take a look at design decisions.

**1: Types**

There are (currently) eighteen types that a Pokemon can be. These types are well-defined and discrete; that is to say, there are no gradients between types and the set of available types do not change dynamically. As a result, types are best represented as an enum.

```
enum class Type {
  Fire,
  Water,
  Grass,
  Electric,
  Fighting,
  Flying,
  Poison,
  Ground,
  Ice,
  Psychic,
  Ghost,
  Dragon,
  Fairy,
  Steel,
  Dark,
  Rock,
  Normal,
  Bug
};
```

There are also no correlations between types and integral values, so the order in the enum does not matter.

In addition, you will want a function somewhere that takes a type and returns a string, being human-readable.

```
std::string TypeToStr(Type type) {
  switch(type) {
  case Type::Fire:
    return "Fire";
  case Type::Water:
    return "Water";
  ...
  default:
    return "ERROR"; //should never get here if you accounted for all types
}
```

**2: Items**

We're gonna need this later. Trust me

```
enum class Item {
  WaterStone,
  FireStone,
  Thunderstone,
  MoonStone,
  LeafStone
};
```

And a method to get the human-readable name

```
std::string ItemToStr(Item item) {
  switch(item) {
  case Item::WaterStone:
    return "Water Stone";
  case Item::FireStone:
    return "Fire Stone";
  case Item::Thunderstone:
    return "Thunderstone";
  ...
  default:
    return "ERROR"; //Should not get here if you accounted for all items
  }
}
```

**3: Evolution**

Most people know Pokemon can evolve. Many of these evolutions are linear (a Krabby can evolve into only a Kingler). But some have branched evolutions. Eevee, in Generation I, can evolve into Jolteon, Flareon or Vaporeon. So what to do? We could store the three pieces of evolution data three times for each Pokemon, even though Eevee is the only one in Gen I that will use more than one. I consider that to be wasteful. We could store evolution data in a vector. That's better, but there's a clever and simple solution: go backwards.

No Pokemon can be evolved to from more than one base form. Let me repeat that: There are no two Pokemon that evolve into the same thing. So we can store our evolution data one per Pokemon and instead of the evolution data saying "This is what you need to do to get to the next stage and this is what the next stage is" it will say "This is how the previous stage got to this form and this is what the previous stage was".

So what does the evolution data look like? Well, in Generation I there are three ways a Pokemon can evolve: Level up (at a certain level), Trade and Stone (with a certain stone). So we have method, data and form. This is what it may look like in code:

```
class Evo {
public:
  Evo(int from) :
    fromID(from)
  {}

  virtual std::string ToStr() = 0;

  int fromID;
};

class EvoTrade : public Evo {
public:
  EvoTrade(int from) :
    Evo(from)
  {}

  virtual std::string ToStr() {
    return " by trading.";
  }
};

class EvoLevel : public Evo {
public:
  EvoLevel(int from, int lvl) :
    Evo(from),
    level(lvl)
  {}

  virtual std::string ToStr() {
    return " by reaching level " + std::to_string(level) + ".";
  }

  int level;
};

class EvoStone : public Evo {
public:
  EvoStone(int from, Item evo_stone) :
    Evo(from),
    stone(evo_stone)
  {}

  virtual std::string ToStr() {
    return " by using a " + ItemToStr(stone) + ".";
  }

  Item stone;
};
```

**5: Genders**

Pokemon have different chances of being male or female. There are also some that are genderless (many legendaries and also Ditto, and some whose design just calls for gender-agnosticism).

**6: Pokemon**

*Finally* we can get here. Okay.

Pokemon can have one or two types (in the dex; in battle, there are cases where they can have three). There are a couple ways to handle this. You could contain a single Type variable and essentially use a bitfield as has been mentioned before, but since a Pokemon can only have up to two types, I think this is overkill. Instead, I would recommend simply having two Type variables. Of course, this presents an extra conundrum.

If we have our Pokemon contain two Type variables, what do we do if the Pokemon has only one type? Say it's a Voltorb, which as you know is Electric only. The second Type variable must contain a valid value, so what do we do? We could introduce a nineteenth type in our enum that serves to mark a type as None, but there is another way. The way the games do it (last I checked) internally is set both variables to the same type. So that is the approach we will follow.

```
class Pokemon {
public:
  std::string name;
  double height, weight; //Metric
  double gender_ratio; //Chance of Male, -1 means genderless
  Evo* evo_data;
  int dex_num;
  Type type_1;
  Type type_2;
  std::function<std::vector<std::string>(int)> get_next_stages;

  Pokemon(int dex_number, const std::string& new_name, double new_height, double new_weight, double male_chance) :
    name(new_name),
    height(new_height),
    weight(new_weight),
    gender_ratio(male_chance),
    dex_num(dex_number),
    evo_data(nullptr)
  {}
  ~Pokemon() {
    delete evo_data;
  }

  std::string ToStr() {
    auto evolves_to = get_next_stages(dex_num);
    std::string answer = 
      "Number: " + std::to_string(dex_num) +
      "\nName: " + name;

      if(type_1 == type_2)
        answer += "\nType: " + TypeToStr(type_1);
      else
        answer += "\nTypes: " + TypeToStr(type_1) + '/' + TypeToStr(type_2);

      answer += "\nHeight: " + std::to_string(height) + 'm' +
      "\nWeight: " + std::to_string(weight) + "kg" +
      "\nMale/Female: ";

      if(gender_ratio < 0)
      {
        answer += "Genderless";
      }
      else
      {
        answer += std::to_string(gender_ratio) + '/';
        answer += std::to_string(1 - gender_ratio);
      }

      for(auto str : evolves_to)
        answer += '\n' + str;

      return answer;
  }

  //These next methods are used to chain setups; they are much more
  //flexible than defining constructors for every possible
  //combination of data setup. And we need to go through methods
  //to set this data up (at least, some of the data) because there
  //are some things we want to do with them

  Pokemon& set_types(Type type) {
    type_1 = type_2 = type;
    return *this;
  }
  Pokemon& set_types(Type type_a, Type type_b) {
    type_1 = type_a;
    type_2 = type_b;
    return *this;
  }

  Pokemon& set_evo_data(Evo* evo) {
    evo_data = evo;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

**7: Final notes**

So what does method chaining look like? Consider the Pokemon class above.

```
Pokemon p1(1, "Bulbasaur", 0.7, 6.9, 87.5)
  .set_types(Type::Grass, Type::Poison);
Pokemon p2(5, "Charmeleon", 1.1, 19, 87.5)
  .set_types(Type::Fire)
  .set_evo_data(new EvoLevel(4, 16));
```

And what about printing that data?

```
//Assuming a collection of Pokemon
std::vector<Pokemon> mons;
//Fill out the data
//...

auto next_stages = [&mons](const int id){
  std::vector<std::string> answer;

  auto found = std::find_if(mons.begin(), mons.end(), [id](const Pokemon& mon){
    return mon.evo_data != nullptr && mon.evo_data->fromID == id;
  });

  if(found != mons.end())
  {
    answer.push_back("Evolves into " + found->name + found->evo_data->toStr());
  }

  return answer;
};

//While filling out the data, put this function as the get_next_stages function
```

Comment: To get things' names, why use a massive `switch` statement when you could instead have a `static` array of `std::string`? Much less boilerplate and computation, ~same storage size. Just ensure the `enum` values start at 0 and don't contain gaps (if either of these aren't true, that seems like a code smell), then define the elements of the array in the same order (copy/paste the `enum` names as comments to make this easier/self-documenting), then use the `enum` to index into it.

Comment: That's definitely a different way of doing it. With only eighteen types and five items that matter in the context of this project for Gen I, I don't see a big difference. On a similar note, should op wish to expand this to other languages or support future generations with their trading with items, I would recommend storing that data (at least the items) in an outside source and read it in that way.

Comment: @underscore_d Your solution might be slightly shorter than using a `switch`, but it's also more fragile.  What happens when someone reorders the enum values, or adds/removes one in the middle, but doesn't change the name array?  Oops, half the stuff now has the wrong name.

Comment: @bcrist True and worth noting; +1. But I get good mileage out of this method in several projects. It just requires an awareness of one's situation and the fact that changes need to be made in 2 places. Plus, I tend to define the `enum`s once and never need to extend them. I guess my cases are simplistic... In a project with multiple committers, who aren't guaranteed to be keenly aware of this constraint, and where new values may arise - then sure, use the `switch`-based method to be safe. Or perhaps, for code that looks nicer but is necessarily slower, some kind of `map` with an `enum` as key.

Answer (score 4):

V nice code. Plus points for

- not doing `using namespace std`
- using standard containers

Comments

Be consistent with naming things, members of Pokemon class `type`, `Gender`.

I would strongly suggest using a special naming convention for member variables. Some dont like this , but I do. so use m_gender or gender_, this makes code clearer in functions, you know what data you are manipulating

I dont think you should have a default constructor. Its meaningless and not needed

Break the code up into functional chunks, LoadPokemons, PrintPoke, PromptUser, ....

Use map not vector. This allows direct lookup rather than linear searching

Notice that you repeat the code for string upper-> lower and vice versa. Make  functions to do this.

Future idea. Load the pokemon data from a file rather than compiling into the program.

Comment: `map` only allows searching on *one* field though--he supports searching on three (and he's never going to have tens of thousands of Pokemon to search through, or anything like that).

Comment: @JerryCoffin considering that we've seen pretty consistent additions of pokemon I wouldn't speak too soon

Comment: @Dannnno: In ~20 years, they've gotten to just over 700 Pokemon. At the rate they're going so far, it'll be ~275 years to get to ten thousand Pokemon.

Comment: I think learning to use map is a useful excercise, I must admit I had not seen the multi key lookup, so OP should use index maps that map keyn to primary key.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I wouldn't be **that** surprised if it lasts another 275 years </facetious>