# Beginner Pokedex in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, pokemon

As a clear copy of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135293/basic-pokedex-in-c), I've written a Pokedex to teach myself the basics of classes, reading from files, using streams etc. I'd really appreciate some feedback on my approach as I'd like to get into good habits early on.

I've got myself the Bjarne Stroustrup C++ book, so my learning should be a little more structured from now on, but this program is a good summary of everything I've learnt so far.

I do also understand that comments should explain why and not how, but many of them are just there so I can make sure I understand what's going on.

**Pokedex.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>

//define global const which is where the Pokedex file is found
const std::string POKEDEX_FILE_NAME = "Data.txt";

//define required Pokemon characteristics at the beginning
typedef int PDexNumber;
typedef std::string Name;
typedef double Weight;
typedef double Height;
typedef int PrevEvo;

//define basic Pokemon types
enum class basicPokemonType
{
    Normal,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Grass,
    Fighting,
    Flying,
    Poison,
    Electric,
    Ground,
    Psychic,
    Rock,
    Ice,
    Bug,
    Dragon,
    Ghost,
    Fairy,
};

basicPokemonType convertStringToType(std::string input)
{
    std::stringstream sstr(input);
    std::string typeString = "";
    sstr >> typeString;

    if (typeString == "Normal")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Normal;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Fire")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Fire;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Water")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Water;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Grass")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Grass;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Fighting")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Fighting;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Flying")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Flying;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Poison")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Poison;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Electric")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Electric;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Ground")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Ground;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Psychic")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Psychic;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Rock")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Rock;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Ice")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Ice;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Bug")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Bug;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Dragon")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Dragon;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Ghost")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Ghost;
    }
    else if (typeString == "Fairy")
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Fairy;
    }
    else
    {
        return basicPokemonType::Normal;
    }
}
std::string convertTypeToString(basicPokemonType input)
{
    if (input == basicPokemonType::Normal)
    {
        return "Normal";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Fire)
    {
        return "Fire";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Water)
    {
        return "Water";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Grass)
    {
        return "Grass";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Fighting)
    {
        return "Fighting";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Flying)
    {
        return "Flying";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Poison)
    {
        return "Poison";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Electric)
    {
        return "Electric";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Ground)
    {
        return "Ground";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Psychic)
    {
        return "Psychic";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Rock)
    {
        return "Rock";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Ice)
    {
        return "Ice";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Bug)
    {
        return "Bug";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Dragon)
    {
        return "Dragon";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Ghost)
    {
        return "Ghost";
    }
    else if (input == basicPokemonType::Fairy)
    {
        return "Fairy";
    }
}

//define Pokemon genders
enum class PokemonGender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Both,
    None,
};
PokemonGender convertStringToPokemonGender(std::string input)
{
    std::stringstream sstr(input);
    std::string gendString = "";

    std::vector<std::string> tempVector;

    while (sstr >> gendString)
    {
        tempVector.push_back(gendString);
    }

    if (tempVector.size() != 1)
    {
        return PokemonGender::Both;
    }
    else if (tempVector.at(0) == "Male")
    {
        return PokemonGender::Male;
    }
    else if (tempVector.at(0) == "Female")
    {
        return PokemonGender::Female;
    }
    else
    {
        return PokemonGender::None;
    }
}
std::string convertPokemonGenderToString(PokemonGender gend)
{
    if (gend == PokemonGender::Male)
    {
        return "Male";
    }
    else if (gend == PokemonGender::Female)
    {
        return "Female";
    }
    else if (gend == PokemonGender::Both)
    {
        return "Male and Female";
    }
    else if (gend == PokemonGender::None)
    {
        return "None";
    }
}

//define Pokemon class
class Pokemon
{
private:
    PDexNumber pdexNumber;
    Name name;
    basicPokemonType type;
    Weight weight;
    Height height;
    PokemonGender gender;
    PrevEvo prevEvo;

public:
    //getter and setter functions
    PDexNumber getpdexNumber(void);
    void setpdexNumber(int num);
    Name getName(void);
    void setName(std::string nm);
    basicPokemonType getType(void);
    void setType(basicPokemonType typ);
    Weight getWeight(void);
    void setWeight(double wgt);
    Height getHeight(void);
    void setHeight(double hgt);
    PokemonGender getGender(void);
    void setGender(PokemonGender gend);
    PrevEvo getprevEvo(void);
    void setPrevEvo(int num);

    Pokemon(PDexNumber pdexNumber, Name name, basicPokemonType type, Weight weight, Height height,
            PokemonGender gender, PrevEvo prevEvo);
};

//code getters and setters for class Pokemon
PDexNumber Pokemon::getpdexNumber (void)
{
    return pdexNumber;
}
void Pokemon::setpdexNumber(int num)
{
    pdexNumber = num;
}
Name Pokemon::getName(void)
{
    return name;
}
void Pokemon::setName(std::string nm)
{
    name = nm;
}
basicPokemonType Pokemon::getType(void)
{
    return type;
}
void Pokemon::setType(basicPokemonType typ)
{
    type = typ;
}
Weight Pokemon::getWeight(void)
{
    return weight;
}
void Pokemon::setWeight(double wgt)
{
    weight = wgt;
}
Height Pokemon::getHeight(void)
{
    return height;
}
void Pokemon::setHeight(double hgt)
{
    height = hgt;
}
PokemonGender Pokemon::getGender(void)
{
    return gender;
}
void Pokemon::setGender(PokemonGender gend)
{
    gender = gend;
}
PrevEvo Pokemon::getprevEvo(void)
{
    return prevEvo;
}
void Pokemon::setPrevEvo(int num)
{
    prevEvo = num;
}
Pokemon::Pokemon(PDexNumber pdexNumber, Name name, basicPokemonType type, Weight weight, Height height,
    PokemonGender gender, PrevEvo prevEvo)
{
    setpdexNumber(pdexNumber);
    setName(name);
    setType(type);
    setWeight(weight);
    setHeight(height);
    setGender(gender);
    setPrevEvo(prevEvo);
}
std::vector<Pokemon> readFileIntoPokemonVector (std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream readFile(filename);
    std::vector<Pokemon> tempPokemon;

    std::string tempPDexNumber = "";
    std::string tempName = "";
    std::string tempType = "";
    std::string tempWeight = "";
    std::string tempHeight = "";
    std::string tempGender = "";
    std::string tempPrevEvo = "";

    std::getline(readFile, tempPDexNumber, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempName, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempType, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempWeight, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempHeight, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempGender, ',');
    std::getline(readFile, tempPrevEvo, ',');

    while (readFile)
    {
        tempPokemon.push_back(Pokemon(std::stoi(tempPDexNumber), tempName, convertStringToType(tempType),
            std::stod(tempWeight), std::stod(tempHeight), convertStringToPokemonGender(tempGender), std::stoi(tempPrevEvo)));

        std::getline(readFile, tempPDexNumber, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempName, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempType, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempWeight, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempHeight, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempGender, ',');
        std::getline(readFile, tempPrevEvo, ',');
    }
    return tempPokemon;
}

 Name returnNextEvoName(PDexNumber origPokemonNum, std::vector<Pokemon> pokemonVector)
{
    //the next evolution is never more than 3 pokemon away
    //(most are two, but Eevee has three)
    //therefore, all we need to do is check the next three pokemon to see if their prevEvo
    //is equal to the pdex number of the one we are looking at

    for (size_t pdexOffset = 1; pdexOffset < 4; pdexOffset++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (pokemonVector.at(origPokemonNum + pdexOffset).getprevEvo() == origPokemonNum + 1)
            {
                return pokemonVector.at(origPokemonNum + pdexOffset).getName();
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return "No further evolutions";
        }
    }
    return "No further evolutions";
}

 Name returnPrevEvoName(PDexNumber origPokemonNum, std::vector<Pokemon> pokemonVector)
 {
     if (pokemonVector.at(origPokemonNum).getprevEvo() == 0)
     {
         return "No previous evolution";
     }
     else
     {
         return pokemonVector.at(pokemonVector.at(origPokemonNum).getprevEvo() - 1).getName();
     }
 }

void PrintPokemon(int pokedexNo, std::vector<Pokemon> pokemonVector)
{
    int numOfCharactersInName = 0;

    if (pokemonVector.empty() == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector is empty.";
    }

    numOfCharactersInName = pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getName().length();
    std::string titleUnderline="-";
    for (int i = 1; i < numOfCharactersInName; i++)
    {
        titleUnderline = titleUnderline + "-";
    }

    std::cout << pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getName() << "\n";
    std::cout << titleUnderline << "\n";
    std::cout << "Pokedex number: " << pokedexNo + 1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "Type: " << convertTypeToString(pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getType()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Height: " << pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getHeight() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Weight: " << pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getWeight() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Gender: " << convertPokemonGenderToString(pokemonVector.at(pokedexNo).getGender()) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Previous Evolution: " << returnPrevEvoName(pokedexNo, pokemonVector) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Next Evolution: " << returnNextEvoName(pokedexNo, pokemonVector) << "\n";
}

//function guarantees that we get a long from user input
long getLongFromUser(std::string strPrompt, long minNum, long maxNum) {

    long result = 0;

    while (true || (result >= minNum && result <= maxNum))
    {

        std::string strinput = "";
        //use getline to avoid errors with inputs
        std::cout << strPrompt;
        std::getline(std::cin, strinput);

        // this line defines a stringstream called 'mystream' and gives it the value of strinput
        std::stringstream myStream(strinput);
        //this line looks for result (i.e. a signed long) and stores it. If it can't, it returns false
        if (myStream >> result) {
            if (result < minNum || result > maxNum)
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter a number between " << minNum << " and " << maxNum << ".\n";
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "That's not a number. Please enter a number.\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //load Pokedex
    std::vector<Pokemon> Pokedex = readFileIntoPokemonVector(POKEDEX_FILE_NAME);
    std::cout << "Welcome to Pokedex!\n";

    long choosePokemon = 0;
    do
    {
        choosePokemon = getLongFromUser("Please enter the number of the Pokemon you want to look up, or enter 0 to exit.\n", 0, 123);
        if (choosePokemon != 0)
        {
            PrintPokemon(choosePokemon - 1, Pokedex); //offset -1 because vectors start at 0
        }
    } while (choosePokemon != 0);   
    return 0;
}
```

**Data.txt**

```
1, Bulbasaur, Grass and Poison, 15.2, 28, Male and Female, 0,
2, Ivysaur, Grass and Poison, 28.7, 39, Male and Female, 1,
3, Venusaur, Grass and Poison, 220.5, 79, Male and Female,2,
4, Charmander, Fire, 18.7, 24, Male and Female, 0,
5, Charmeleon, Fire, 41.9, 44, Male and Female, 4,
6, Charizard, Fire and Flying, 199.5, 67, Male and Female, 5,
7, Squirtle, Water, 19.8, 20, Male and Female, 0,
8, Wartortle, Water, 49.6, 39, Male and Female, 7,
9, Blastoise, Water, 188.5, 63, Male and Female, 8,
10, Caterpie, Bug, 6.4, 12, Male and Female, 0,
11, Metapod, Bug, 21.8, 28, Male and Female, 10,
12, Butterfree, Bug and Flying, 70.5, 43, Male and Female, 11,
13, Weedle, Bug and Poison, 7.1, 12, Male and Female, 0,
14, Kakuna, Bug and Poison, 22, 24, Male and Female, 13,
15, Beedrill, Bug and Poison, 65, 39, Male and Female, 14,
16, Pidgey, Normal and Flying, 4, 12, Male and Female, 0,
17, Pidgeotto, Normal and Flying, 66.1, 43, Male and Female, 16,
18, Pidgeot, Normal and Flying, 87.1, 59, Male and Female, 17,
19, Rattata, Normal, 7.7, 12, Male and Female, 0,
20, Raticate, Normal, 40.8, 28, Male and Female, 19,
21, Spearow, Normal and Flying, 4.4, 12, Male and Female, 0,
22, Fearow, Normal and Flying, 83.8, 47, Male and Female, 21,
23, Ekans, Poison, 15.2, 79, Male and Female, 0,
24, Arbok, Poison, 143.3, 138, Male and Female, 23,
25, Pikachu, Electric, 13.2, 16, Male and Female, 0,
26, Raichu, Electric, 66.1, 31, Male and Female, 25,
27, Sandshrew, Ground, 26.5, 24, Male and Female, 0,
28, Sandslash, Ground, 65, 39, Male and Female, 27,
29, Nidoran female, Poison, 15.4, 16, Female, 0,
30, Nidorina, Poison, 44.1, 31, Female, 29,
31, Nidoqueen, Poison and Ground, 132.3, 51, Female, 30,
32, Nidoran Male, Poison, 19.8, 20, Male, 0,
33, Nidorino, Poison, 43, 35, Male, 32,
34, Nidoking, Poison and Ground, 136.7, 55, Male, 33,
35, Clefairy, Fairy, 16.5, 24, Male and Female, 0,
36, Clefable, Fairy, 88.2, 51, Male and Female, 35,
37, Vulpix, Fire, 21.8, 24, Male and Female, 0,
38, Ninetales, Fire, 43.9, 43, Male and Female, 37,
39, Jigglypuff, Normal and Fairy, 12.1, 20, Male and Female, 0,
40, Wigglytuff, Normal and Fairy, 26.5, 39, Male and Female, 39,
41, Zubat, Poison and Flying, 16.5, 31, Male and Female, 0,
42, Golbat, Poison and Flying, 121.3, 63, Male and Female, 41,
43, Oddish, Grass and Poison, 11.9, 20, Male and Female, 0,
44, Gloom, Grass and Poison, 19, 31, Male and Female, 43,
45, Vileplume, Grass and Poison, 41, 47, Male and Female, 44,
46, Paras, Bug and Grass, 11.9, 12, Male and Female, 0,
47, Parasect, Bug and Grass, 65, 39, Male and Female, 46,
48, Venonat, Bug and Poison, 66.1, 39, Male and Female, 0,
49, Venomoth, Bug and Poison, 27.6, 59, Male and Female, 48,
50, Diglett, Ground, 1.8, 8, Male and Female, 0,
51, Dugtrio, Ground, 73.4, 28, Male and Female,52,
52, Meowth, Normal, 9.3, 16, Male and Female, 0,
53, Persian, Normal, 70.5, 39, Male and Female, 52,
54, Psyduck, Water, 43.2, 31, Male and Female, 0,
55, Golduck, Water, 168.9, 67, Male and Female, 54,
56, Mankey, Fighting, 61.7, 20, Male and Female, 0,
57, Primeape, Fighting, 70.5, 39, Male and Female, 56,
58, Growlithe, Fire, 41.9, 28, Male and Female, 0,
59, Arcanine, Fire, 341.7, 63, Male and Female, 58,
60, Poliwag, Water, 27.3, 24, Male and Female, 0,
61, Poliwhirl, Water, 44.1, 39, Male and Female, 60,
62, Poliwrath, Water and Fighting, 119, 51, Male and Female, 61,
63, Abra, Psychic, 43, 35, Male and Female, 0,
64, Kadabra, Psychic, 124.6, 51, Male and Female, 63,
65, Alakazam, Psychic, 105.8, 59, Male and Female, 64,
66, Machop, Fighting, 43, 31, Male and Female, 0,
67, Machoke, Fighting, 155.4, 59, Male and Female,66,
68, Machamp, Fighting, 286.6, 63, Male and Female, 67,
69, Bellsprout, Grass and Poison, 8.8, 28, Male and Female, 0,
70, Weepinbell, Grass and Poison, 14.1, 39, Male and Female, 69,
71, Victreebel, Grass and Poison, 34.2, 67, Male and Female, 70,
72, Tentacool, Water and Poison, 100.3, 35, Male and Female, 0,
73, Tentacruel, Water and Poison, 121.3, 63, Male and Female, 72,
74, Geodude, Rock and Ground, 44.1, 16, Male and Female, 0,
75, Graveler, Rock and Ground, 231.5, 39, Male and Female, 74,
76, Golem, Rock and Ground, 661.4, 31, Male and Female, 75,
77, Ponyta, Fire, 66.1, 39, Male and Female, 0,
78, Rapidash, Fire, 209.4, 67, Male and Female, 77,
79, Slowpoke, Water and Psychic, 79.4, 47, Male and Female, 0,
80, Slowbro, Water and Psychic, 173.1, 63, Male and Female, 79,
81, Magnemite, Electric and Steel, 13.2, 12, None, 0,
82, Magneton, Electric and Steel, 132.3, 39, None, 81,
83, Farfetch'd, Normal and Flying, 33.1, 31, Male and Female, 0,
84, Doduo, Normal and Flying, 86.4, 45, Male and Female, 0,
85, Dodrio, Normal and Flying, 187.8, 71, Male and Female, 84,
86, Seel, Water, 198.4, 43, Male and Female, 0,
87, Dewgong, Water and Ice, 264.6, 67, Male and Female, 86,
88, Grimer, Poison, 66.1, 35, Male and Female, 0,
89, Muk, Poison, 66.1, 47, Male and Female, 88,
90, Shellder, Water, 8.8, 12, Male and Female, 0,
91, Cloyster, Water and Ice, 292.1, 59, Male and Female, 90,
92, Gastly, Ghost and Poison, 0.2, 51, Male and Female, 0,
93, Haunter, Ghost and Poison, 0.2, 63, Male and Female, 92,
94, Gengar, Ghost and Poison, 89.3, 59, Male and Female, 93,
95, Onix, Rock and Ground, 463, 346, Male and Female, 0,
96, Drowzee, Psychic, 71.4, 39, Male and Female, 0,
97, Hypno, Psychic, 166.7, 63, Male and Female, 96,
98, Krabby, Water, 14.3, 16, Male and Female, 0,
99, Kingler, Water, 132.3, 51, Male and Female, 98,
100, Voltorb, Electric, 22.9, 20, None, 0,
101, Electrode, Electric, 146.8, 47, Male and Female, 100,
102, Exeggcute, Grass and Psychic, 5.5, 16, Male and Female, 0,
103, Exeggutor, Grass and Psychic, 264.6, 79, Male and Female,102,
104, Cubone, Ground, 14.3, 16, Male and Female, 0,
105, Marowak, Ground, 99.2, 39, Male and Female, 104,
106, Hitmonlee, Fighting, 109.8, 59, Male, 0,
107, Hitmonchan, Fighting, 110.7, 55, Male, 0,
108, Lickitung, Normal, 144.4, 47, Male and Female, 0,
109, Koffing, Poison, 2.2, 24, Male and Female, 0,
110, Weezing, Poison, 20.9, 47, Male and Female, 109,
111, Rhyhorn, Ground and Rock, 253.5, 39, Male and Female,0,
112, Rhydon, Ground and Rock, 264.6, 75, Male and Female, 111,
113, Chansey, Normal, 76.3, 43, Female, 0,
114, Tangela, Grass, 77.2, 39, Male and Female, 0,
115, Kangaskhan, Normal, 176.4, 87, Female, 0,
116, Horsea, Water, 17.6, 16, Male and Gender, 0,
117, Seadra, Water, 55.1, 47, Male and Female, 116,
118, Goldeen, Water, 33.1, 24, Male and Female, 0,
119, Seaking, Water, 86, 51, Male and Female, 118,
120, Staryu, Water, 76.1, 31, None, 0,
121, Starmie, Water and Psychic, 176.4, 43, None, 120,
122, Mr. Mime, Fairy and Psychic, 120, 51, Male and Female, 0,
123, Scyther, Bug and Flying, 123.5, 59, Male and Female, 0,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't obfuscate standard types

The current code includes these lines:

```
typedef int PDexNumber;
typedef std::string Name;
typedef double Weight;
typedef double Height;
typedef int PrevEvo;
```

Then it uses these like this:

```
PDexNumber pdexNumber;
Name name;
basicPokemonType type;
Weight weight;
Height height;
PokemonGender gender;
PrevEvo prevEvo;
```

This is not only unhelpful but counterproductive.  Experienced programmers know what a `double` is, but would have to look up what a `Weight` is.  That's bad.  Instead, we want programmers to be able to read the code *without* a lot of effort, so just omit these `typedef`s.

### C++ isn't Java

Don't create "setters and getters" for every data member.  C++ is not Java and C++ programmers simply don't do that.  The reason is that if you need to have unfettered read and write access to every data member, simply declare them all to be `public`.  However, in most cases, this isn't really needed.  Be selective about revealing the internals of your class.

### Use C++ idioms

Instead of defining a standalone `PrintPokemon` in the way you've done, I'd recommend instead to define a overload for `ostream &operator<<` for the `Pokemon` class.  Here's one way to write it.  First, within the class declare a `friend` function like so:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Pokemon &p);
```

Then outside the class declaration, we define the function:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Pokemon &p) {
    return out << p.name << '\n'
            << std::string(p.name.size(), '-') 
            << "\nPokedex number: " << p.pdexNumber 
            << "\nType: " << convertTypeToString(p.type)
            << "\nHeight: " << p.height
            << "\nWeight: " << p.weight
            << "\nGender: " << convertPokemonGenderToString(p.gender);
}
```

Note that this doesn't yet print the *Previous Evolution* and *Next Evolution*, but I'll address that in a later suggestion.

### Use modern constructors

The code you've got already requires C++11, so there's no reason not to use modern style constructors.  Specifically, write the constructor like this:

```
Pokemon::Pokemon(int pdexNumber, std::string name, basicPokemonType type, double weight, 
    double height, PokemonGender gender, int prevEvo)
:
    pdexNumber(pdexNumber),
    name(name),
    type(type),
    weight(weight),
    height(height),
    gender(gender),
    prevEvo(prevEvo)
{}
```

This eliminates the need for all of those ugly and repetitive setters.

### Encapsulate definitions within classes where logical

There is probably little use for a `PokemonGender` without an associated Pokemon, so I'd suggest putting that `enum` within the `Pokemon` class.  Even better, in my view, would be to rethink how it will be used.  Ultimately, there are fixed number of categories and associated strings.  I'd suggest that perhaps instead of an `enum`, that a `std::array` of `std::string` or `const char *` might be more appropriate.  Here's how I would do it.  First, I'd change the type of `gender` to `unsigned` within the private data members of the `Pokemon` class.  Then I'd declare the following items within that class:

```
static constexpr std::array<const char *, 4> genders{"Male", "Female", "Male and Female", "None"};
static unsigned stringToGender(std::string &tempGender);   
const char *getGender() const;
```

Then outside the class, the following definitions:

```
constexpr std::array<const char *, 4> Pokemon::genders;

const char *Pokemon::getGender() const {
    return genders[gender];
}
unsigned Pokemon::stringToGender(std::string &tempGender) {
    unsigned retval{0};
    for (const auto &label : genders) {
        if (label == tempGender) {
            break;
        }
        ++retval;
    }
    return retval == genders.size() ? genders.size()-1 : retval;
}
```

You can do a similar thing  with the Pokemon types (with a bit more work, since each can have multiple types) and the resulting code is both shorter and easier to read.

### Avoid "magic numbers"

Instead of hardcoding 123 as the upper limit, it would be better to use `Pokedex.size()` so that the actual vector size as read from the file is being used rather than some hardcoded number.

### Rethink your classes

There are really two kinds of objects in the existing program.  First is the Pokemon and second is a collection of them.  Because the relationships among them are important, I'd suggest that either there could be a `PokemonCollection` object or that there should be `preEvo` and `nextEvo` pointers within each `Pokemon` class.  Either is a valid approach, but I suspect that having a `PokemonCollection` object would be handier.  It would be convenient, for example, to see the hierarchy of a particular Pokemon evolution without having to guess at index numbers.  Either way, the hierarchy should be determined once as the input is read and then simply used, rather than having to recalculate it each time it's needed.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: No, these typedefs do nothing to prevent adding a Weight and Height -- try it.  Also, **if** Weight were a class, then I'd say use the class name.  Still no need for a typedef -- it's only pointless obfuscation in this context.

Comment: Oh, duh, of course you're right.  I had already made the leap in my mind that these typedefs had been replaced by classes to solve this exact problem!  Sorry about that.

Comment: But I still stand by strong typing as a way to avoid these problems (acknowledging that typedef isn't strong typing.) I always go back to examples like the Mars Climate Observer incident, where the impulse supplied was in units of type "US-customary" instead of the expected "SI-metric". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure

Comment: Thanks Edward, really appreciate your help. I especially like the idea of overloading operator<<. Quick question regarding the 'getters and setters' - are you in effect saying that, in C++, I should only really code as I require? In other words, I create the data members as private and then only create accessing functions as I need?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write less code using maps in functios like `basicPokemonType convertStringToType(std::string input)`, `std::string convertTypeToString(basicPokemonType input)`, etc.

Example:

```
std::map<std::string, basicPokemonType> MapStringToPokemonType = { {"Normal", basicPokemonType::Normal}, 
                                                                   {"Fire",   basicPokemonType::Fire}, 
                                                                   {"Water",  basicPokemonType::Water} 
                                                                 };

basicPokemonType convertStringToType(std::string input)
{
    basicPokemonType result;

    try {
        result = MapStringToPokemonType.at(input);
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
        result = basicPokemonType::Normal;
    }    

    return result;
}
```

About your *required* custom types at the beginning:

```
typedef int PDexNumber;
typedef std::string Name;
typedef double Weight;
typedef double Height;
typedef int PrevEvo;
```

I think that they don't help you to make clearer your code, look at this:

```
PDexNumber pdexNumber;
Name name;
basicPokemonType type;
Weight weight;
Height height;
PokemonGender gender;
PrevEvo prevEvo;
```

You are writing twice the same concept... or this function:

```
Name getName(void);
```

I think that you could use standard types like `double` or `std::string` to get more information.

```
string name;
string getName(void);
```